# Animateness-neutral "its"

Tags: american-english, grammatical-number, collective-nouns, animacy, notional-concord

> *The House of Representatives shall chuse their* [modernly, *its*]
> *Speaker*.
>
> U.S. Const. art. I, § 2

Wouldn't the use of *its* here be "animateness-neutral", so to speak, as opposed to *their*?

Comment: who are you quoting, or are those "scare-quotes" around *animateness-neutral*?

Comment: @vectory kinda; it's an expression of my own

Comment: So the question is whether yours is a good description? It's hardly common or standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a singular *they*, as your tags imply it might be, but a plural *they*. In modern American English, we usually treat collective nouns as singular. "The company puts out a press release most weeks, but it skipped this week."

In the usage you quote (and sometimes in modern Commonwealth English), the collective noun is being treated as a group of people. "The company put out a press release most weeks, but they skipped this week."

Comment: It's not actually so black and white. It's easy to pull up plenty of present-day examples of American English speakers using plural *they* for companies and organizations.

Comment: 'In the usage you quote (and sometimes this occurs in modern Commonwealth English), the collective noun is being treated as a group of people.' though you could probably get away with 'In the usage you quote (and sometimes in modern Commonwealth English), the collective noun is treated as a group of people.' Though the punctive and the habitual are sneakily conflated in the latter.

Comment: @tchrist 'The House of Commons shall choose its Speaker' sounds faintly cartoonish, with an animated Palace of Westminster stroking its chin. Obviously there has to be some degree of notionality / logical fiddle with any form of agreement here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the auxiliary verb masks the verbal agreement; would a verb in the singular or plural trigger _its_ or _their_, respectively ? Secondly, what exactly does **shal**l mean here, regarding the traditional distinction _shall vs will_ in the first persons?

Comment: @GJC The House of Commons elect their Speaker next week. // Near obsolete niceties now, but 'shall' has to imply an imperious command here.

Answer (score 1):

The quoted sentence is using "House of Representatives" to mean *members* of that body.  So the plural pronoun is perfectly appropriate, 232 years ago and now.